# DB authentication failed - postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I don't know why I got this error message:

```
DB authentication failed:
    SequelizeConnectionError: Ident authentication failed for user "smemamian"
        at connection.connect.err (/home/sunyar/API/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:108:24)
```

the `\l` command line output:

```
postgres=> \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 sunyar    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres+
           |          |          |             |             | sunyardb=CTc/postgres+
           |          |          |             |             | smemamian=c/postgres
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

my db connection variable:

```
DB_CONNECTION_URL = 'postgres://smemamian:123456@localhost:5432/sunyar'
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, postgres uses IDENT-based authentication. So, "Ident authentication failed" is related to the **pg_hba.conf** configuration file. From the `psql` command line, you can locate this file by typing:

```
postgres=> show hba_file;
```

Check out the reference here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html